# Set Date Time to Jquery date time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have date in Javascript

```
Sun Feb 15 2015 08:02:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

how I can to set in format '`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`' into datetime picker?

If I set like this:

> dateStart
>
> Sun Feb 15 2015 08:02:00 GMT+0200 (EET)
>
> $('#dateTimeStart').datetimepicker('setDate', dateStart);
>
> Error parsing the date/time string: Missing number at position 10
> date/time string = 02-15-2015 08:02:00
> timeFormat = HH:mm
> dateFormat = mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: if you solve issue . then please mention here. and close question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change format of date from server in this : '`02/15/2015 08:02:00 AM`'
and then I parse this string and create new date:

```
var dateString ='02/15/2015 08:02:00 AM';
var dateStart = new Date(Date.parse(dateString, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
$('#dateTimeStart').datetimepicker('setDate', dateStart);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#dateTimeStart').datetimepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm'
        timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss"
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to format date that you have. You can do it with help of function that you can grab [here](https://github.com/phstc/jquery-dateFormat).

Usage:

```
<script>
  document.write($.format.date("Sun Feb 15 2015 08:02:00", "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
</script>
```

It's small and really nice solution that can help you to resolve your issue.

Comment: But he is using datetimepicker

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a format like

```
jQuery('#dateTimeStart').datetimepicker({
    format:'d/m/Y H:i:s'
});
```

According to the DateTimePicker documentation at http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/, the 'format' string is based on the PHP date format strings, which you can read up on at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php. Note in particular they use just one letter to represent multiple numbers (e.g. 'd' instead of 'dd')

Answer (score 0):

use below javascript code to change formate

```
 var date = new Date('Sun Feb 15 2015 08:02:00 GMT+0200');

 var day    = date.getDate();
 var month  = date.getMonth();
 var year  = date.getFullYear();
 var hours = date.getHours();
 var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
 var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

 var fulldate = day+'/'+(month+1)+'/'+year+' '+hours + ':' + minutes.substr(minutes.length-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(seconds.length-2);
```

see working copy of [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Le6bun1j/1/)

you can create function which return date in format

```
function convertdate(param){
    var date = new Date(param);
    var day    = date.getDate();
    var month  = date.getMonth();
    var year  = date.getFullYear();
    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = "0" + date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = "0" + date.getSeconds();

    return fulldate = day+'/'+(month+1)+'/'+year+' '+hours + ':' + minutes.substr(minutes.length-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(seconds.length-2);
}
alert(convertdate('Sun Feb 15 2015 08:02:00 GMT+0200'));
```